# How to add gradient color in echarts?

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts, apache-echarts

I made a echart [line graph](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqghec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
Now, I want to add gradient color to it, as shown below:
[image]

In this [link](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.areaStyle.color), it said it supports the setting as gradient color. But when I tried to do this as code given:[image]

It gave this error:
[image]

What to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  areaStyle: {
          color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
            {
              offset: 0,
              color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
            },
            {
              offset: 1,
              color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
            }])
        }
```

Echart has graphic class, which gives you access to the Gradient Property. You can fine tune it to your needs giving start and end points to the colors in array.

Comment: where will I get `graphic`? I tried this one before. It gives this error, `Cannot find name 'graphic' `

Comment: `import { graphic } from 'echarts'`. graphic is instantiated from the echarts itself.

Comment: Thanks alot. Would you mind giving me one upvote for the question?

Comment: If you are not using Angular/npm, but plain javascript directly. Use: `new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient()`

Comment: How do I use the color picked from the palette for each series, and only apply opacity to each stop?